# "10800 = X" riddle

Tags: in-another-world-with-my-smartphone

In volume 8 of *In Another World With My Smartphone*, Touya (the MC) encounters ruins containing riddles. Whilst the novel explains the questions and answers to most of them, one of them has me confused:

> "Please follow the rules of the current calculation. In this system, what does X equal?" 36 = 1, 108 = 3, 2160 = 2, 10800 = X.

Touya claims the answer was straightforward and proceeds. But, whilst it may have been straightforward to him, I don't get it. If required, I can supply the answer he gives, but, I didn't want to spoil it.

Comment: I suggest checking out https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ site for puzzles and riddles like this one. Even if it comes from anime, I don't think this is the best place to ask, and not being able to find "riddle" tags is an indication of that :p Also, perhaps include some screenshots or pictures if you can and if it you think it would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are probably many possible answers, the most common answer is

> **10800 = 5**, or **X = 5**.

Hints:

1. > "0" is 1,"1" is 0, etc. (the puzzle usually avoids "4" because it's ambiguous)
2. > Count the loop on each digit.
3. > Only "0", "6", "8" and "9" have loop(s) on their digits.

Solution:

> "10800" has 5 loops; 3 from "0" and 2 from "8", thus X = 5.

Comment: Related question on [math.se]: [Puzzling Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1075450)

Answer (score 0):

36 = 1, 108 = 3, 2160 = 2, 10800 = X.

Possible formula:-
First set patern
36 = 1
108 = 3 [ 108/36 =3 ]

Second set with similar patern
2160 = 2
10800 = X [ 10800/2160 =5 ]

X=5

There are few possibility of formulas, but the simplest is the above which meet the patern requirement. It does not matter if 2160 = "?" just follow the first set patern "108/36 =3" which will lead to "10800/2160" and you get the answer X=5.

Comment: While it may be another valid thought process, it's unlikely that "2160 = 2" has no meaning...